# Open menu from two different buttons

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a designer with some coding experience but my JS is very poor.

I am using the Bootstrap-Offcanvas code from

https://github.com/iamphill/Bootstrap-Offcanvas

and although its great I can't see how i can open the menu from two different buttons on the same page.

the JS is here:
https://codepen.io/TMDESIGNS/pen/RygvjQ

I have tried this

```
 $("js-bootstrap-offcanvas").trigger("offcanvas.open");
```

I want the seach icon to open the menu also, but nothing i try works

can anyone help?

Comment: Hi do you have fiddle for your code ?

Comment: Not at the moment, when i get a mo i will put it up.

Answer (score 2):

YOu have to add and event listener to a button (you want to use to open menu). Something like this:

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => $("#js-bootstrap-offcanvas").trigger("offcanvas.open"), false);
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I have inlcuded the code in a code pen, but haven't add this code.

https://codepen.io/TMDESIGNS/pen/RygvjQ